# Error starting Siddhi App in WSO2 Stream Processor: javax/jms/JMSContext

Tags: wso2, siddhi, tibco-ems, wso2-streaming-integrator

**I'm trying to use a queue from Tibco EMS as a source of the Siddhi application.**

For that, I used the [documentation about ActiveMQ](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Supporting+Different+Transports#SupportingDifferentTransports-JMStransportJMS) as a reference and generated successfully the OSGi-converted jar for the tibjms.jar.

Within this step I was able to Register the InitialContextFactory:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\STREAM~1\446521~1.0\bin>icf-provider.bat com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory C:/DevTools/tibjms.jar C:/DevTools/
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\STREAM~1\446521~1.0\bin\..
Feb 18, 2020 10:46:05 PM org.wso2.carbon.tools.spi.ICFProviderTool execute
INFO: Executing 'jar uf C:\DevTools\tibjms\tibjms.jar -C C:\DevTools\tibjms \internal\CustomBundleActivator.class'
Feb 18, 2020 10:46:05 PM org.wso2.carbon.tools.spi.ICFProviderTool addBundleActivatorHeader
INFO: Running jar to bundle conversion
Feb 18, 2020 10:46:06 PM org.wso2.carbon.tools.converter.utils.BundleGeneratorUtils convertFromJarToBundle
INFO: Created the OSGi bundle tibjms_1.0.0.jar for JAR file C:\DevTools\tibjms\tibjms.jar
```

Then, I created the OSGI-converted jars for the remaining tibco ems jars:

- jms-2.0.jar
- tibemsd_sec.jar
- tibjmsadmin.jar
- tibjmsapps.jar
- tibjmsufo.jar
- tibrvjms.jar

At this point, I copied all the OSGI jars to the "/lib" directory and the original jars to the "/samples/sample-clients/lib" directory.

Next, I sent a couple messages to the queue "queue.sample" with the textbody "hello queue".

Then, I created the following Siddhi application to use the EMS queue a source:

```
 @App:name('TIBCOQueueSource')
@App:description('Use EMS que as SP source')

@source(type = 'jms', destination = "queue.sample", factory.initial = "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory", provider.url = "tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222", transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName= "QueueConnectionFactory", transport.jms.UserName= "admin", transport.jms.Password = "admin",@map(type = 'text'))
define stream inputStream (name string);

@info(name='query_name')
from inputStream
select name
insert into outputStream;

from outputStream#log("logger")
select *
insert into tmp;
```

Finally, when I ran the event simulator I got the following error in the logs:

```
[2020-02-18 22:59:31,006] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiAppRuntime} - Error starting Siddhi App 'TIBCOQueueSource', triggering shutdown process. javax/jms/JMSContext
```

So, based on this discription am I doing something wrong? Am i missing any step of the process?

Tks in advance for all the help